# Django - ContentType Does Not Exist for own app

Tags: django, django-contenttypes

I'm trying to learn how to use the ContentTypes framework, I can't seem to get it to find my own apps.

The docs [have clear instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#the-contenttype-model) for importing a model from django.contrib.sites, which works for me. However, when I try to substitute my own app and model, I am unsuccessful.

I have a model at MyApp.Events.models.Event. I try to call:

`i = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="Events", model="Event")`

in response, console prints:

> django.contrib.contenttypes.models.DoesNotExist: ContentType matching
>   query does not exist.

I tried this as well which also failed:

`i = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="events", model="event")`

I have `'django.contrib.contenttypes'` as well as this app listed under installed apps. Is there another setting I am missing to enable this functionality?

Comment: Did you run migrations?

Comment: Yes, I've run all of the migrations and restarted the shell.

Comment: can you find the contenttypes in the shell by making the query you did above?

Comment: No, this is the result I am getting from the shell. It isn't working for any of the models in any of my three apps. The models themselves are working as expected with the rest of my project.

Comment: so the contenttype table is empty?

Comment: It seems to work for Django's built in apps. It works with `ContentType.objects.get(app_label="Sites", model="Site"` as shown in the docs.

Comment: I have had contenttypes installed since I set up the project, but I haven't done anything else to configure it. I can't seem to find anything in the docs about this other than `"new instances of ContentType are automatically created whenever new models are installed"`. But it seems like this requires something I'm not doing.

Comment: then either your app_label or model name is wrong here in the query.

Comment: contenttypes is installed and runs per default. No need for extra settings. not that I know..

Comment: Well, I can successfully do an import `from MyApp.Events.models import Event` and run queries there.

Comment: just look into your db, is the row `events, event` there?

Comment: Aha! Thanks for the tip. Apparently postgres drops the case on the model, but not the app. I found `Events_event` in the db and tried this with success :)

Comment: cool, glad that you got it ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since no one else posted it, here is the solution.

`i = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="Events", model="event")`

Even if your model is capitalized in your `models.py`, it gets saved in all lowercase. I don't know if this is Django's idea of funny or PostgreSQL's, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Great answer, I would like to point out that SQLite3 users might experience something similar, and that models are saved in lowercase too. So this answer will work too.
Note to further users : try to look in the database django_content_type for the right names.